# FCM notification not work on USA location

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have registered my application on FCM console for push notification. now when I am sending notification via FCM console (Notifications). My client is not able to get that in USA location.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a question for FCM

Comment: Yes it is question for FCM but related to push notification in iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your client has enabled his notifications in Device Settings.